# Bluetooth: one device for input and one for output

Tags: bluetooth

Good morning everyone!

I am wondering, is it possible on Android 9 to use a Bluetooth headset as voice input and a Bluetooth speaker as output at the same time?

Context: I need to run my voice through a modulator!